# Pass request parameters through FacesContext

Tags: jsf-2, parameter-passing, actionlistener, managed-bean

I moved from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 and it seems I missed something during the switch. I have following scenario:

1. There is a button on one page with actionListener set to one managed bean's method which adds an object to request by calling `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("foo", fooObject);`
2. Navigation is properly handled to other page where other managed bean is initialized.
3. The constructor of other managed bean tries to retrieve passed object from request by calling `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("foo");` and to initialize itself with received values.

Both managed beans are request scoped. I notice that constructor can't retrieve proper value from request because request map doesn't contain "foo" key.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In step 2, if there is a redirect the initial request scope is lost as the redirect would result in another request.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, you're absolutely right. There was <redirect> element in faces-config.xml and when I removed it parameters were correctly passed.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge. Much appreciated.